# Ionic Toggle and Angular with localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have problem with save values to localStorage with ionic toggle. I tried many thing. One of the solution works on web browser but not on device.

Here is my code:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="enable" ng-change="toggle()" toggle-class="toggle-balanced" value="{{enable\}}">I want notification</ion-toggle>
```

Here is my angular:

```
  var enable = window.localStorage.getItem('enable');

  if (enable=='true') { enable=true; } else if (enable=='false') { enable=false; }

  $scope.enable = enable;

  $scope.toggle = function() {
      if ($scope.enable == false) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('enable', true);
      } else {
        window.localStorage.setItem('enable', false);
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use?

```
var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item"));
localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(item));
```